# Bash script for a slideshow with image list refresh

Tags: bash, shell, slideshow, watch, inotify

I'm writing a short script for a slideshow using `fbi`. For sake of completeness, the script gets executed after an automatic login on an Ubuntu machine, which should run headless; the machine only external interface should be a Samba folder where I add/remove images.
I started easy:

```
usr/bin/fbi -noverbose -a -t 4 -u `find -type f | egrep -i "(jpg|bmp|png|gif)$"`
```

This works fine: `find`/`egrep` return a list of files that `fbi` shows at 4 seconds interval.
Now, I need to refresh my slide list when a new image gets added or an existing one gets deleted. I tried `watch`, without success.

If I execute from command line this:

```
watch -n 300 -t `find -type f | egrep -i "(jpg|bmp|png|gif)$"`
```

I get the same list of files and whenever I add an image to my target folder, the list gets updated within next 5 minutes. Fine. But when I add this to my script, nothing works:

```
/usr/bin/fbi -noverbose -a -t 4 -u `watch -n 300 -t 'find -type f | egrep -i "(jpg|bmp|png|gif)$"'`
```

With this, I get nothing and when I interrupt the slideshow, my command line is screwed (no carriage return, no typing echo...).

What am I doing wrong/overlooking/missing? Or am I completely off target?

Because another solution would be to have two scripts, the slideshow's one and a controller script (maybe using inotify-tools), killing and restarting the slideshow script when target folder gets modified.

Any suggestion or tip, veeeery appreciated!

rash*

Comment: `watch` doesn't look too good for scripts, I think you should use a `while` loop and the `sleep` command

Comment: @golimar: yeah, thanks, a friend already warned me about watch being not suited for scripts... I'm really a bash newbie...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
watch -n 300 -t `find -type f | egrep -i "(jpg|bmp|png|gif)$"`
```

What this is doing, because you've used backticks, is passing the list of filenames to `watch`, which I suspect you don't want to do. **Maybe** this would work, but I don't have any way to test:

```
watch -n 300 -t '/usr/bin/fbi -noverbose -a -t 4 -u `find -type f | egrep -i "(jpg|bmp|png|gif)$"`'
```

Though this brings up the thorny question of just how many copies of `fbi` will be running after a few days.

Probably your best bet would be to set up a cron job to run a script like this every *x* minutes:

```
#!/bin/bash
pkill -f /usr/bin/fbi
shopt globstar
cd /your/images/directory
files=(**/*.jpg **/*.bmp **/*.png **/*.gif)
usr/bin/fbi -noverbose -a -t 4 -u "${files[@]}"
```

Instead of using `find` and `grep`, I used `bash` [globbing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob), which is safe for filenames with spaces, and also saves you running two other commands! This requires bash 4+ for the globstar option that provides recursive matching.

The globbing gives you file names in an array, which is passed directly to `fbi`, as described in [Bash FAQ 50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#I.27m_constructing_a_command_based_on_information_that_is_only_known_at_run_time)

Comment: thanks a ton! I've chosen your answer 'cause not only solved my issue but it also anticipated a few additional problems (like: I hadn't yet shot at the problems with win-like filenames, which globstar addresses brilliantly, so I've also learned an additional thing...).
Thanks a lot, again!

Comment: I'd like to post my final solution, which starts from your answer and builds on it, solving a nasty issue (nasty to me, at least). What's the right way to do it?

Comment: You can edit my question to add your stuff, if it's too long to fit in comments.